# How to check if device is LTE, 3G, HSPA or Wi-Fi?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cellular-network

Is it possible to determine which kind of network is on the device when the user is interacting with my app?

Right now I have the Reachability class and I can differentiate between Wi-Fi and Cellular, but how to check if the Cellular is LTE, 3G, HSPA, EDGE?

Comment: I won't recommend doing that. Just because you have a low LTE connection it does not guarantee that is faster then a 3G connection.

Comment: I don't care how fast the LTE network is. In the end it's faster than HSPA and EDGE, right?

Comment: No, LTE has the capacities to be able to be faster then other technologies. For example when using 3G in the mountains of Austria you will get lower download rates then when using EDGE. That's because the 3G signal is very bad but it still there so the iPhone will try to use it. The same occurs to the still unfinished LTE network. In short: LTE can be slower then 3G, 3G can be slower then EDGE and so on. In most cases the real download rate will be much more informative then the cellular network type.

Comment: So what will you advice me? To not differentiate any cellular networks, just differentiate cellular and wi-fi?

Comment: Depends on for what you would need to differ. You can measure the download rates or just differentiate cellular and wi-fi.

Comment: For most use cases, it's enough to tell WiFi and Cellular apart. By the Way, that's what apple suggests anyways. Because sometimes Edge can be faster then 3G and 3G faster then LTE. Cellular data can be quite hard to get your head around.

Comment: Check out this Stack Overflow Post <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562119/iphone-app-alert-users-when-they-arent-connected-to-the-internet>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS7, information about the cellular connection is available using CTTelephonyNetworkInfo():

```
let info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
print(“carrierName": " + "\(info.subscriberCellularProvider?.carrierName ?? "Has not been configured for carrier")")
print(“currentRadioAccessTechnology: " + "\(info.currentRadioAccessTechnology ?? "Airplane Mode/No cell connection")")
```

currentRadioAccessTechnology will show a string that describes the type of connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to differentiate between different types of cellular network.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668021/is-there-any-way-to-know-what-network-an-iphone-is-connected-to-lte-vs-gsm) for some further information.